# Unable to add or copy gas-preprocessor.pl in usr/bin on macOS Sierra

Tags: ios, macos-sierra

Im trying to add gas-preprocessor.pl to usr/bin. Adding it to usr/local/bin does not work.

I tried switching to root user and performing the action. The operation to copy or add this file is still not permitted.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: usually you need to craete a symbolic link in those folders and not a simple copy of the file. After that u should restart the console

Answer (score 1):

Since creating a soft link doesnt work for me, this link helped for the work around. http://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2016/07/30/docker-usrlocalbindocker-machine-permission-denied/

Command: sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin

Comment: you save my life!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ln -s gaspreprocessor/path /usr/bin/local/gaspreprocessor
```

Be sure gaspp is executable